# OpenGL pixel buffer directly to screen in Linux and Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, opengl, screen, buffer

I'm looking for a way to render a pixel buffer directly to a screen. I need a way to do it on both OSX and Linux, although I know I will probably need to do it through different methods for each OS (although a cross platform library would be nice.) Where do you start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use an orthographic projection of a quad to your backbuffer/surface.

Or just send the quad in NDC space (-1 to +1) without needing any matrix multiplication.

**Update** because this apparently isn't clear enough:

For the "fullscreen quad" approach, send two tris or one quad like this:

[image]

The configuration/order of verts is dependant on your winding order and the primitive mode. `Z` value should be between `-1` to `1`. You can just choose `-1`. Projection and ModelView matrix should be an identity matrix (that is all zeros, then 1's on the main diagonal)

[image]

In other words you dont need to do any matrix multiplication so you dont actually need any matrix ops in your shaders, since the coords are already in Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC).

i.e. it is alread inside the target device interval of [image]

Here is some code:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW); 
glPushMatrix (); 
    glLoadIdentity (); 
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION); 
    glPushMatrix (); 
        glLoadIdentity ();
        glBegin (GL_QUADS); 
        glVertex3i (-1, -1, -1); 
        glVertex3i (1, -1, -1); 
        glVertex3i (1, 1, -1); 
        glVertex3i (-1, 1, -1); 
        glEnd ();
    glPopMatrix (); 
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW); 
glPopMatrix ();
```

The vertex shader is then just a direct passthrough to the pixel/fragment shader. Obviously you would set the relevant pixel/texture buffer as a shader resource/variable and sample it in the pixel/fragment shader. And dont forget to set the texcoord UV's of the vertexes to their corresponding texture values (`0-1`).

Alternatively you could also use the corresponding windowing system to blit the texture directly to the window surface. This is highly dependant on what you are using for window management (e.g. SDL) and may also require a certain texture format/layout to work (or conversion).

Comment: How do you do it? Do you have a link of how is done? Or some code?

Comment: @BЈовић I dont deserve the downvote. What I wrote is universally true of all graphics APIs. What I wrote gives enough information to "start" - there are countless examples all over the internet; the OP asked for where to start. I believe in giving theory instead of writing someones code for them, but I will indulge you by giving some examples.